# UIPinchGestureRecognizer require two touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I have added the following gesture recognizers to a view:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pch= [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ViewPinching:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:pch];

// and

UIPanGestureRecognizer *d = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ViewDragging:)];
[d setMinimumNumberOfTouches:4];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:d];
```

I want to fire the event when 4 fingers are dragged and when I do that the Pinch gesture recognizer fires instead of the Pan gesture recognizer. I was thinking that maybe I could fix this problem if I restrict the UIPinchGestureRecognizer to be fired only if touches.count=2

### edit

I don't know if this will be practical or not. Maybe I could add:

```
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pch= [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(ViewPinching:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:pch];
```

every time touches start if there is two touches I will add that event and remove it ontouchesended.

Comment: Bad idea:  4 fingers is a multitasking gesture that will close your app on iOS 5

Comment: true. how can I restrict it so that it only works with 2 fingers and 4 or more then...

Comment: Nope.  You'll need your own subclass of UIGestureRecognizer, as UIPinchGestureRecognizer only responds to 2 or 1 finger touches (any more are ignored).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ultimately a bad idea.  A 4-finger pinch in iOS 5 will close your app, and a 4 finger pan will switch to the next app (obviously not good for UX).  If you *absolutely* must use 4 fingers, make a subclass of UIGestureRecognizer and do the pinching logic yourself.  Let me apologize ahead of time for not having an example, as your use case is quite unique.

Comment: I totally agree thanks for reminding me that. I am creating an app where depending on the gesture I will fire a specific command therefore I want to have as many gestures as possible. I will enable pinching with 4 or more fingers but I will like to restrict pinching with 3 fingers. when I slide 3 fingers, more often the pinching method fires than the uipan one...

Comment: Remove the pinch then.  And make gestures unique, because apple is really starting to narrow the ones we can feasibly use.  Maybe a checkmark gesture, or a one finger rotation gesture (which is possible, and really cool).

Comment: for example logmein ignition has all this features. and the pinch only work in their app with two fingers. I wonder how they do that... I will try it for a little more and if I just can't make it work you are right I will just remove the pinching functionality.